# Prove that a sequence that satisfies $a_n − a_{n−1} \leq a_{n+1} − a_n$ is monotone

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $a_n$ is a sequence satisfying  $a_n − a_{n−1} \leq a_{n+1} − a_n$ $\forall n\gt1$, prove that $a_n$ is monotone from some point onwards.

I think this is probably quite straightforward, but I can't see how to prove that $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ or $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$ from the above inequality.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What about the sequence $3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$?

Comment: @peterwhy  right. If there is some $N$ with $a_N < a_{N+1}$  the sequence is monotone after that.

Comment: @peterwhy. Good point, it should be monotone from some point onwards, like your sequence.

Comment: @Mittens that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @GregMartin. I'll give that a shot

Comment: The term *monotone* may be ambiguous.  It would help if you are referring to strictly increasing, strictly non-decreasing, strictly decreasing, strictly non-increasing, or some combination of the above.

Comment: The condition implies that the graph of this sequence is concave up, so either it’s monotone decreasing for all $n$, or there comes a point at which it changes from monotone decreasing to monotone increasing (and stays that way forever after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

1. **If there is a positive integer $k$ such that $a_{k+1}-a_k$ is positive:** Let $k_0$ be the first integer such that $a_{k_0+1}-a_{k_0}$ is positive. Then the relation $a_{k_0} < a_{k_0+1}$ follows. Furthermore, $a_{k_0+2} -a_{k_0+1}$ is also positive [why] implying the relation $a_{k_0+1}  < a_{k_0+2}$. In fact, for each integer $i  \ge 0$ it follows that $a_{k_0+i+1} -a_{k_0+i}$ must also be positive [why] implying the relation $a_{k_0+i} < a_{k_0+i+1}$ for each such $i$. Can you conclude $$a_{k_0} <a_{k_0+1} < a_{k_0+2} <$$ $$\cdots < a_{k_0+i} < a_{k_0+i+1} <\cdots $$ and thus $a_{k_0}, a_{k_0+1}, a_{k_0+2}, \ldots$ is a monotonically increasing sequence.
2. **If there is no such $k$ such that $a_{k+1}-a_k$ is positive,** then it follows that $a_{k+1}-a_k \le 0$ for each integer $k$, or equivalently, $a_{k} \ge a_{k+1}$ for each integer $k$. So the sequence is monotonically nonincreasing.

[Check that

- the sequence defined by $a_n =2^{-n}$ and
- the sequence defined by $a_n = 1$ $\forall n=1,2,\ldots$ [the $a_n$s stay the same]

satisfy the conditions in the OP. Furthermore in each such sequence there is no integer $k$ s.t. $a_{k+1}-a_k$ is positive.]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get the downvotes. It's a simple problem. Another way to look at it:

Let $M = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n+1} - a_n$, where $M$ can be infinity or a finite value. This $M$ will exist since the differences $a_{n+1} - a_n$ are increasing.

If $M = \infty$, for large enough $n$ one has $a_{n+1} - a_n >1$, so the sequence is eventually increasing. If $0 < M < \infty$, then for large enough $n$ one has $a_{n + 1} - a_n > {M \over 2}$, so the sequence is eventually increasing. If $M \leq 0$, then for all $n$ one has $a_{n+1} - a_n \leq 0$, so the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: $a_{n+1} - a_n = -2^{-n-1}$ here, which increase to $M = 0$. So the sequence is decreasing.

Comment: The proof is correct. If the *increasing* sequence $(a_{n + 1} - a_n)$ converges to some $M \le 0$ then $a_{n + 1} - a_n \le 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: I downvoted the original version as I found it hard to follow. Did you mean $b_n$ nonpositive for one integer $n$ or every integer $n$, for example? On that note, did the 'eventually' modify the 'nonpositive' as well as the 'nonnegative'? You also certainly don't need the monotone sequence theorem to show this either [was that part of the proof or not, I couldn't tell]

Comment: The edited version is clearer, but still seems more convoluted than it needs be....we can avoid the whole issue of taking limits and as to whether there is indeed a limit M in the first place, see my above answer.

Comment: Five lines wouldn't normally be considered convoluted (and I didn't leave anything as an exercise, as you did.) The existence of the limit of a monotone sequence is pretty standard in an analysis course.